# Синтаксическая ошибка }

Tags: php, yii2

Я установил ubuntu и развернул проект у себя на локалке, после запуска выдает слелующую ошибку:

> syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file

```
<?php foreach ($poolGroups as $pool){ ?>
ошибка на этой строчке <? php } ?>
```

если же я использую:

```
<? foreach ($poolGroups as $pool): ?>
<? php endforeach; ?>
```

все работает
смотрел другие ответы на похожий вопрос, нужно было в php.ini включить 
short_open_tag=On
но у меня все равно ничего не заработало

Comment: Почему вы пишете `< ?` а не `<?`?

Comment: так я написал только для данного сообщения, в коде: <?foreach ($tmp as $value){?>
                    <option value="<?=$value['path']?>"><?=$value['name']?></option>
                <?php }?>

Comment: И зачем вы так написали?

Comment: При записи без пробелов по какой-то причине код не отображался в сообщении, теперь исправил вроде норм

Comment: `теперь исправил` - разве? До сих пор вижу `<? php` вместо `<?php`.  Добавьте целиком настоящий ваш код, который вызывает ошибку(и без которого ошибки нет)

Comment: <?php foreach ($tmp as $value){?>
                    <option value="<?=$value['path']?>"><?=$value['name']?></option>
                <?php }?> в общем если я ставлю после <? название php то работает, если же <? без ничего то выдает ошибку, проект не маленький и не хотелось бы везде добавлять php

Comment: Выдержка из стандарта psr1 "Files MUST use only <?php and <?= tags."

Comment: Спасибо) но почему на проде работает и с показанным мной синтаксисом. Без php

Answer (score 2):

у вас ошибка в теле цикла, тк изолированный пример, рабочий:

```
<?php foreach ($variable as $key => $value) { ?>
    <?= $value ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: вовсе нет ошибка в другом, выше я ответил про суть проблемы

Comment: да, понятно. не увидел ваш комментарий

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($poolGroups as $pool) : ?>
<?= $value ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```